# Is this the correct metric to Virgils Georgics II, 459?

Tags: classical-latin, poetry, vergilius, scansion, metre

> **a**grícó/l**a**s quíbús /**i**psá pró/c**u**l dis/c**o**rdíbús/ **a**rmis

Is this correct? I tried to indicate the short syllables with the accents. I would appreciate your answer very much!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is absolutely correct!
You have identified the long and short syllables correctly, and from that the scansion follows.
To be sure, it is always good to check that the pattern fits the metre and there is a natural place for at least one caesura.
Once these all check out, your scansion is usually right.